# Chain error throws in multi level promises Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, try-catch

I would like to chain different errors comming from differents level promises and **have one error on the last catch** !

Imagine we have the following situation :

```
this.methodOne().then( responseOne =>{

    this.methodTwo(responseOne ).then( responseTwo =>{
       console.log(responseTwo );
     }).catch(err => {
      // send err to last catch
      throw err;
     })

 }).catch(err => {
  // Show err one or two
  console.log(err)
})
```

But is not working

Thank you

Comment: In general, an inner catch is only necessary if 
(a) you want to inspect the error (remember to re-throw the error)
(b) you want to inject a custom error message (change error.message and re-throw, or throw a new Error)
(c) you want to inject a default value to stand in place of what should have been delivered to the success path (return the value).
Otherwise, don't catch.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the inner promise for the `throw` to propagate.  Inner promises are only added to the chain when you return them from the `.then()` handler.  When you do that, they are inserted into the chain and their resolved or rejected state is what the outer promise chain gets.  Without the `return`, the inner promise chain is just it's own independent promise chain that isn't connected to the outer one at all.

So, change this:

```
this.methodOne().then( responseOne =>{

    this.methodTwo(responseOne ).then( responseTwo =>{
       console.log(responseTwo );
     }).catch(err => {
      // send err to last catch
      throw err;
     })

 }).catch(err => {
  // Show err one or two
  console.log(err)
})
```

to this:

```
this.methodOne().then(responseOne => {

    // ADD return on next line to return inner promise
    //    to add this inner promise chain to the outer chain
    return this.methodTwo(responseOne ).then(responseTwo => {
       console.log(responseTwo );
       return responseTwo;       // return this so it becomes the resolved
                                 //   value of parent chain too
     }).catch(err => {
       // send err to last catch
       throw err;
     });

 }).catch(err => {
  // Show err one or two
  console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: @BorisDetry - Since it looks like you may be new here, if this answered your question, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  This will also earn you some reputation points here on the site for following the proper procedure.